# Flask and default file for static folder invocation (index.html, etc.)

Tags: python, flask, webserver

With Flask, serving static content

how can I configure flask to serve `index.html` or `index.html`
when the user requests the folder... like `"http://example.com/xxx/"`

---

(as the default behavoiur in Apache/IIS/nginx/etc.)

Comment: Why not just use Apache/IIS/nginx/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory) to send files from a directory, which can be pretty convenient in some situations:

```
@app.route('/somepath/<path:path>')
def send_html(path):
    return send_from_directory('some_folder', path)
```

Comment: I'd only use it to serve static assets.